# How TyphoonScopeObjectGraph works

Tags: ios, typhoon

Let say, I have the code below

```
self.customObj = self.assembly.customObj() as? NSObject
let temp3 = self.assembly.customObj() as NSObject
```

If I use `TyphoonScopeObjectGraph` for `customObj`, it should return the same instance.
But when I debug, the `customObj` properties are not the same as shown:
[image]

As far as I understand, `customObj` and `temp3` should be the same instance. But as you see in the image, `customObj` and `temp3` have the same `ObjectiveC.NSObject` address but all of its properties (`_shortFormatter`, `_longFormatter`) have different address. What happen? How we can get the same instance for `customObj` and `temp3`. An example is very helpful. 
Thanks.

You can get the project source code from [here](https://github.com/sahara108/Typhoon-Swift-Example/tree/master/PocketForecast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example above if you want `self.customObj` and `temp3` to be the same instance, then you need either `TyphoonScopeSingleton` or `TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton`.

The way `TyphoonScopeObjectGraph` works is that *during resolution* if two instances declare that they depend on another component called `context`, then the same shared instance of `context` will be returned. However these are not retained by Typhoon. So you can load a whole object graph (eg a view controller, along with dependencies) and then discard it when done, rather than use singletons, as you might otherwise. `TyphoonScopeObjectGraph` is also useful for having circular dependencies, such a a controller and view, that has a delegate property pointing back to the controller.

It helps to explain with an example: Let's say we have:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) InjectedClass(ShoppingCart) cart;
@property(nonatomic, strong) InjectedClass(MyView) view;

@end

@interface MyView : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) InjectedClass(ShoppingCart) cart;

@end

//ShoppingCart has object-graph scope
@interface ShoppingCart
@end
```

Now if we ask Typhoon to give us an instance of of `MyViewController`, then a controller will be returned where both `MyViewController` and `MyView` will have the same instance of `ShoppingCart`

- If TyphoonScopePrototype was used, then each would have a different instance of `ShoppingCart`
- If TyphoonScopeSingleton was used, then each would have the same instance of shopping cart, but there'd be no way to release the memory.

. . so you see `TyphoonScopeObjectGraph` loads an object graph with shared instances, but allows that whole object graph to be discarded after the use-case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand  *if two instances declare that they depend on context then the same shared instance of context will be returned.* Could you please send me an example? Another thing in my question that I don't understand is that `self.customObj` and `temp3` have the same `ObjectiveC.NSObject` address (see the image in my question). So that it should be the same instance, isn't it?

Comment: Extended the answer - understand now? About the ObjectiveC.NSObject, probably they have the same isa-pointer (or in other words they are both instances of the same class).

Comment: The example is helpful. Thank you.